# Independence of SATA channels and ports

Tags: linux, raid, sata

I'm working on setting up a simple RAID and am wondering about how independent my SATA ports really are. There are 4 ports on the motherboard, but `lspci` shows only two controllers

```
00:0e.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 7350
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at b800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at b480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at b400 [size=8]
    I/O ports at b080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at b000 [size=16]
    Memory at fbffd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [cc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv

00:0f.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 7350
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at ac00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at a880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at a800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at a480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at a400 [size=16]
    Memory at fbffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [cc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv
```

The kernel log at boot shows

```
ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xb800 ctl 0xb480 bmdma 0xb000 irq 21
ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xb400 ctl 0xb080 bmdma 0xb008 irq 21
ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xac00 ctl 0xa880 bmdma 0xa400 irq 20
ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xa800 ctl 0xa480 bmdma 0xa408 irq 20
```

Would this mean I have two channels with two ports each? If so, a RAID 1 with two drives should ideally be set up with each drive on a separate channel (although performance may not really be noticeable)? Or is each port still independent?

Answer (score 0):

> Would this mean I have two channels with two ports each?

No. Each regular SATA 'channel' only connects to one drive.

The exception to that would be if you used a [port multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier), but that is quite uncommon in consumer space and depending on the type of multiplier you would need to explicitly configure it.  Since you do not mention doing that I am answering "No" to this part of the question.

> If so, a RAID 1 with two drives should ideally be set up with each drive 
>   on a separate channel (although performance may not really be noticeable)?
>   Or is each port still independent?

For IDE/P-ATA you are right.  For SATA this should not matter.

Question: If your BIOS/controller configured for the normal AHCI mode or are you booting in legacy mode? The latter might explain why you are seeing old-style information when you list the PCI configuration.